# Undirected graphs + runtime

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I have recently started studying graphs and their different traversal algorithms, and can't seem to be able to come up with answers to these two questions. I really need your help, I don't even know where to start.

*(a) Prove that every connected graph G=(V,E) has a node v∈V such that removing vv and all its adjacent edges will not disconnect G.*

*(b) For a given connected graph G=(V,E), design an O(n+m)-time algorithm to find such a node.*

I have found some answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200729/graph-run-time-nodes-and-edges), but they still don't make a lot of sense to me because I don't have a lot of experience in the topic.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136926/subway-graphs